# Alamofire support for ios14

Tags: alamofire, ios14

I have a method headerParameters() which returns [String: String]? when I tried migrating code to swift 5 to support iOS14 I tried upgrading the Alamofire version and getting an error as "Cannot find 'SessionManager' in scope" can someone help me with this.

```
func headerParameters() -> [String: String]? {
        return SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
    }
```

Comment: Nothing related to alamofire and iOS 14. It is related to your swift code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire 5 renamed `SessionManager` to `Session` and moved the `defaultHTTPHeaders` to the `HTTPHeaders.default` value.